Github action create an issue with body a table
- name: Create Issue
  if: steps.check_issue.outputs.issue_exists == 'false'
  run: |
       issue_body=$(echo '{
        "title": "Titolo ${{  steps.check_repo.outputs.code }}",
        "body": "${{  steps.check_repo.outputs.table }}"
       }')
       curl -X POST -H "Authorization: token ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" -d "$issue_body" https://api.github.com/repos/${GITHUB_REPOSITORY}/issues


I'm trying to create an issue automatically via github action with body a table as seen below, but it's not working, I'm having the following problems that can be seen in the image.
The table instead of wrapping the elements, they should all be on a single line but with a \n instead of wrapping, I tried | tr '\n' '\\n' I couldn't do it, can you help me.

how does it show on github?

What do you mean how does it display on github? the table is generated by a js script that uses something similar for example: let table = "| repository | commit | latestCommit |\n|--|--|--|\n"; 
`setOutput("table", createTable(repositories));`

Then when I access the variable the \n disappear and are replaced by an automatic line.

@DanielA.White: If I use \n instead of word wrapping it works, but I'm not sure how to do it because I have a variable from which I get the table.

You can not use multiline strings in JSON. You have to use "\n" to encode multiline. This works for me:
issue_body='{
  "title": "Titolo",
  "body": "|a|b|\n|-|-|\n|1|2|"
}'

curl -X POST -H "Authorization: token ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" -d "$issue_body" https://api.github.com/repos/${GITHUB_REPOSITORY}/issues

The following complete workflow works for me in converting a multiline string sent via an output to an encoded multiline and JSON payload. awk is used to read input line by line and output each line followed by 2 characters "" and "n". awk removes LF character '\n' when reading input lines.
name: multiline-body

on:
  workflow_dispatch

jobs:
  create-issue:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Output multiline table
        id: check_repo
        run: |
          {
          echo "table<<EOF"
          echo '| a | b |
          |---|---|
          | 1 | 2 |
          '
          echo EOF
          } >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
      - name: Create table environment
        run: |
          echo -n "table=${{ steps.check_repo.outputs.table }}" | awk '{printf "%s\\n", $0}' >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: Create Issue
        run: |
          issue_body='{
            "title": "Titolo",
            "body": "${{ env.table }}"
          }'

          curl -X POST -H "Authorization: token ${{ secrets.PAT }}" -d "$issue_body" https://api.github.com/repos/${GITHUB_REPOSITORY}/issues


In fact, if you read the messages above, I said it, but I can't solve it.

Updated my answer to provide multiline encoding.

It seems to work but I get the following message, what could be the reason: https://i.sstatic.net/AJ2mqnt8.png

Is this inside an IDE? It probably can not parse the atypical syntax of placing a variable into env context. You may want to break that statement into two - create local variable ‘table’ and then place it into GITHUB_ENV the regular way: echo “table=$table” >> $GITHUB_ENV.    This static analysis error, however, should not matter to the runtime - the variable is created in env context

In fact, you do not need the environment variable in the env context I only introduced it to make the creation of issue_body more readable. You could create a local environment variable in the last step and then inject it into issue_body. However, you would have to use double quotes which would require you to escape double quotes in the JSON.

I tried to edit the file automatically on github by accessing dev mode: https://github.com/github/dev

Look: https://i.sstatic.net/O7xePF18.png

Yes, looks like static analysis.
